# Elasticsearch - template matcing based on field value

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine this document:

```
{
    "_index": "project.datasync.20180101",
    "_type": "com.redhat.viaq.common",
    "service": "data-sync-server",
    "data": {
        "foo":"bar"
    }
    ...
}
```

I would like to have mapping for "data.foo" field (imagine I need some changes in how it is indexed etc.)

I know I can match indices like this:

```
{
    "template" : "project.datasync.*",
    "order" : 100,
    "mappings": {
        "data": {
            "enabled": true,
            "properties": {
                 "foo": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed", ...}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the `datasync` part in the index name comes from somewhere else and there's no guarantee that it will be `datasync` or something similar that matches a pattern. 
So, my index template wouldn't match if the index is `project.thedatasync.20180101`.

I know I can use `project.*` in my index template for matching, but in that case it is too generic where it matches irrelevant things.

So, I would like to have this mapping active only when `service` is `data-sync-server` which is always true for the documents that I am interested in.

Any ideas? This seemed like something fundamentally against how ElasticSearch works and in that case I would like to clarify that.

Please note that documents are sent to ElasticSearch with Fluentd I don't have access to Fluentd config to change the index name there.

Comment: Reading my question again: I think what I am looking for is basically mapping rules defined by document data, not index name. We could simplify the problem like that. Still don't know if it is possible and not sure if ElasticSearch fundamantally differs.

Comment: Maybe [`match` and `unmatch` in mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#match-unmatch) are what you are looking for? There are also `match_pattern`, `path_match`, and `path_unmatch`, which could come in handy for your usecase.

Comment: What I understand is they don't provide matching field by values and only matching by field name is possible

Comment: Yes. If you require very dynamic fields you could use a pattern like `int_foobar`, `string_foobar`,... — that's a common workaround. But generally too sparse isn't great for Lucene; it improved in 7, but I'd be careful with field explosions.